# Detect the end of line in file

Tags: java, file, line, file-handling

I am trying to read a `txt` file and display the file elements. I want to display elements in same line to give a single line break. But, give extra new line when new line in file starts. The `txt` file is:

> Interstellar % Christopher Nolan % 2014 % PG-13
>
> Inception % Christopher Nolan % 2010 % PG-13
>
> Endgame % Russo Brothers % 2019 % PG-13

Here, `%` is delimeter. What I have done so far:

```
File file_path = new File("film.txt");
try {
    Scanner file_input = new Scanner(file_path);
    file_input.useDelimiter("%");
    for(new_book=1; file_input.hasNext(); new_book++) {
        String book_item = file_input.next().trim();
        System.out.println(book_item);
        if(new_book%4==0){
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    file_input.close();
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File not found");
}
```

What it gives:

```
Interstellar 
Christopher Nolan
2014
PG-13
Inception 

Christopher Nolan
2010
PG-13
Endgame 
Russo Brothers

2019 
PG-13
```

What I want is:

```
Interstellar 
Christopher Nolan
2014
PG-13

Inception 
Christopher Nolan
2010
PG-13
```

What I have noticed is, at the end of line indexing is not working i.e, if I print `new_book` then, `new_book` value is not shown in first and second `PG-13`, but shows in last `PG-13`.

I am confused with this line in file. Every suggestion is appreciated!!! Also, note that I am not confuse with syntactical error. But, with the logic and how file reading process is done.

Comment: Is this really the code you are using?

Comment: Yes, I thought it will work.

Comment: I don't think you're running this code. It's missing a closing `}` and uses `-` as the delimiter. It probably differs from your real code in other ways too. Can you post a self contained example that shows the problem?

Comment: Now I have editted... Thanks for that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the line break is not considered as a delimiter so the 4th token is read as `PG-13<NEWLINE>Inception` - with a line break embedded inside. Your options are:

Add line break as a possible delimiter:

```
Scanner file_input = new Scanner(file_path);
file_input.useDelimiter("%|\n");
```

Or add % at the end of every line in the input file:

> Interstellar % Christopher Nolan % 2014 % PG-13 %
>   Inception % Christopher Nolan % 2010 % PG-13 %

Or change the way the file is read to reading line by line and splitting on `%` (see answers by others)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to read the line and then split it

```
file_input = new Scanner(file);
while(file_input.hasNextLine()){
    String st = file_input.nextLine();
    String[] s = st.split("%");
    if(s.length > 1)
        System.out.println(s[0] + "\n" + s[1] + "\n" + s[2] + "\n" + s[3] + "\n");
}
file_input.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the scanner.nextLine() function to read the entire line at once. Then  I split the line string into a list of strings with String.split("%"). Finally I used String.trim() on each String before outputting to remove leading and trailling whitespace.

```java
File file_path = new File("film.txt");
try {
    Scanner file_input = new Scanner(file_path);
    while(file_input.hasNextLine()){
        String line = file_input.nextLine();
        String[] items = line.split("%");

        for(String item: items)
            System.out.println(item.trim());

        System.out.println();

    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```